# JavaScript :"TypeError: Cannot set property 'monthDay' of undefined under ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

My code:

```
(function(exports) {
   var name = ["January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June","July",
                "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
   exports.month = function(number) {
     return name[number];
   };
   exports.number = function(number) {
     return name.indexOf(number);
   };
})(this.monthDay = {});

console.log(monthDay.number("April"));
```

I get the following error under ES6:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'monthDay' of undefined

But , it can work well under ES5.Why?

Comment: If you're running the code in strict mode or an ES6 module, `this` is `undefined` rather than a reference to the global object.

Comment: The scope of the variable is within the function. instead use `window.monthDay = {}` in it